# C Store array element address in other element

Tags: c, types, addressing

What data type would I use to store the address of other elements in an array.

As in, element 0 of an array has the address of element 5. And so on..

Comment: use size_t (i.e. int) elements and store the _index._ Add it to the array address.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer can be converted into an `int` (or a `long` if you are doing 64-bit and your c compiler defines `long` as 64 bits). Then you need only get the address of the element you are trying to point to.

```
int test[10];
test[0] = (int)&test[5];
```

Comment: `intptr_t` might be a better type choice, as that type is guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer value.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `uintptr_t`?

Comment: I won't edit, I'd basically have to rewrite the entire post :) `intptr_t` is defined on the system if and only if there's an integral type that's big enough. AFAIK there is no difference between using this and `uintptr_t`

Answer (score 1):

The address of an element has a different data type to the element. So your code is going to have to involve some type conversion.

To do it with minimal casting:

```
T some_object;

void *array[20];
array[0] = &some_object;
array[5] = &array[0];

// ....

T *some_ptr = *(void **)array[5];
```

Comment: @Peter, that would rely on `void *` and `T *` having identical representation and alignment requirements.

Comment: It also missed an indirection. Btw, all of this is only implementation defined, isn't it?

Comment: I'm also not sure whether the OP wants to involve a separate T. My gut feeling is that the projection of recursive self referencing into the type system is the point here. Because in effect an element could hold a ******T, if the pointing is chained far enough.

Comment: My version is well-defined, any pointer can be converted to `void *` and then have the original pointer retrieved. However my version is less useful if the OP intends to have longer chains of pointers , in that case he's probably better off using your idea and making that assumption.